# wordpress update not working and showing no error($wpdb->update)

Tags: wordpress

In my knowledge, I have done everything correctly. I can confirm that the table name is correct(aupair_registered_employee_prefferred_countries), ID is correct. I dont understand why it fails. Also, the "last_error and "last_query" are no help. it cant detect the error. At this point I dont know how to move forward with this.

```
function update_employee($request){
    global $wpdb;
    $data = array(
        'wp_user_id'   => 70,
        'country'      => 'Sloveniax',
        'is_activated' => 1,
        'year_created' => 2020,
    );
    $where      = array('ID' => 27);
    $result     = $wpdb->update('aupair_registered_employee_prefferred_countries', $data, $data_where);
    if($result){
        wp_send_json_success("SUCCESS : ".$wpdb->last_error);
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error("ERROR21 : ".$wpdb->last_error." RESULT ".$result);
    }
    die();
}
```

//aupair_registered_employee_prefferred_countries
[image]

Can anyone shed some light on me on this one!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `$wpdb->prefix` to table name.

```
function update_employee($request){
    global $wpdb;
    $data_update = array(
        'firstname' => $request['firstName'],
        'lastname'  => $request['lastName'],
    );
    $data_where = array('ID' => '7');
    $result     = $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.'aupair_registered_employee', $data_update, $data_where);
    if($result){
        wp_send_json_success("SUCCESS : ".$wpdb->last_error);
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error("ERROR : ".$wpdb->last_query);
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried your approach and it cant find the table. By the way my full table name is "aupair_registered_employee".

Comment: This is the log "Table 'activeau_workplatform.aupair_aupair_registered_employee' doesn't exist", so what i did is remove the "aupair", to make "registered_employee". But still not working

Comment: Can you share the screenshots of the database with that table?

Comment: but only show with `aupair_registered_employee` this table name.

Comment: i have tried updating a table with less column it still wont work, i am going to edit my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231525/discussion-between-luna-moonfang-and-bhautik).

Answer (score 0):

I used "$data_where" instead of just "$where". Also, if somebody has this issue make sure that before updating, you have udpated any value. Wordpress update wont trigger unless there is any value that is updated.